# show images from amazon with 304 status

Tags: php, caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have my amazon s3 service active, and I figure out how to upload object with header and cache control.

```
$s3->putObject(array(
                    'Bucket'     => 'album',
                    'Key'        => $filename,
                    'SourceFile' => $image[0]->getRealPath(),
                    'ContentType' => $image[0]->getMimeType(),
                    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
                    'CacheControl' => 'max-age=172800',
                    "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years")),
                    'Metadata' => array(

                        'album' => 'al',

                    ),
                ));
```

But then when i want to show this object how can i tell to php to say, Hey check this image from amazon if has the status 304, show up the cached image, if no get the content. any help please

Comment: You can do CURL HEAD request and get just the headers from PHP. If return code is 304, show cached image otherwise, get content. But, I have a question... why are you loading files from PHP? let the browser do that directly from S3 endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for this suggest, I will really appreciate if you can do an example about what you said. I drilled my head reading thousand of posts but still I don't understand how leverage a cache images system, on s3 specific in this case. :) Ps: you said "If return code is 304, show cached image otherwise, get content" how can do it in PHP?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I see it like this... you have a site coded in PHP. Your assets are in S3. When some one loads pages in browser, your PHP serves the page. Then the browser makes subsequent requests to fetch the images and stuff. Correct? If this is the case, the way you are loading images to your server from S3 then serving is waste of resources. What you can do is, redirect users to S3 directly. In your image tag, instead of pointing to relative URL, point to S3 end point.

Comment: let's talk in chat if you want :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51873/show-images-from-amazon-with-304-status I'll explain you better

Comment: I'm in London time zone. Available next on Tuesday :)